# The following error is raised when I try to use twilio-ruby gem "warning: LoadError: cannot load such file -- rack/media_type"

Tags: ruby, twilio

I am currently attempting to `require "twilio-ruby"` in a ruby file after adding it to my gemfile and doing `$bundle install`, however I keep getting the following error message when attempting to load the file in `irb` `< warning: LoadError: cannot load such file -- rack/media_type >`

The error pathing leads back to `.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/irb/init.rb:397`

My gemfile currently looks like

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '3.1.1'


group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false, group: :test
  gem 'simplecov-console', require: false, group: :test
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rubocop', '1.20'
  gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 5.61', '>= 5.61.1'
end
```

My code look like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'

class SMS

  def send_sms(message)
    account_sid = ENV["TWILIO_SID"]
    auth_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]

    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

        @client.messages.create(
      from: ENV["TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER"],
      to: ENV['PHONE_NUMBER'],
      body: message
    )
  end

end
```

I have tried this with and without `require 'rubygems'` but it keep coming up with the same error

I have done checked and my `gem list` does include `twilio-ruby (5.65.0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've found a bug in `twilio-ruby`! Recently there was an update to the gem changing some behaviour in a rack middleware that is part of the gem. It lead to the gem requiring some behaviour from Rack, but in a situation where Rack isn't loaded, like your code above, this fails because Rack isn't a dependency.

I've just made [a PR to fix this](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/pull/602). To fix this in the meantime, you can downgrade the version of `twilio-ruby` to 5.63.0, before the previous change was merged, or you can install rack as a dependency.

The library is released every two weeks and the last release was February 24th. So if this fix is approved quickly, it could make it into this release.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is sorted now! :)

Comment: Awesome, if this answer helped do you mind marking it as correct so that other people can see that too? Thanks!

Comment: This is fixed in 5.65.1 now.

Comment: @philnash I'm still getting this error in v5.66.1. I also tried v5.65.1  Downgrading to 5.63.0 solves my problem. Would you still like a stack trace or anything of the sort?

Comment: If you are still seeing this error, then it would be most useful if you could [raise an issue](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/issues) and share how you're using the gem and any stack traces. Thank you!